# The CAMERA_BUTTON intent cannot be caught by receiver

Tags: android, key, capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to listen to camera capture in Broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482381/android-how-to-listen-to-camera-capture-in-broadcastreceiver)

I want to awake my app by one key pressing. But I found it's not easy to implement on Android.

I am trying to capture camera key and then  launch my app. BUT the onReceive() function is not called after camera key pressing.

Here is what in manifest.xml

```
<reciever android:enabled="true"  android:name=".SaveUKeyCapture">
    <intent-filter android:priority = "10000">
    <action android:name = "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON"/>
    <action android:name = "android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" /> 
    <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
    </intent-filter>
</reciever>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Here is the code

```
public class SaveUKeyCapture extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Toast.makeText(context, "intent received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any one has any idea about the issue ? thanks!

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this, I am basically using the same code along with android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA, and the only apps that show up when I press the camera button are Camera and Vignette.