# Android: How to listen to camera capture in Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

I saw many posts in StackOverflow regarding how to listen to camera events, and got few information but still there are few questions remain in my mind please let me know the answers for these:

I have an application which have a broadcast receiver and my broadcast receiver will lauch my activity, but the main purpose of having broadcast receiver is to listen to camera photo/video capture intent.

I want to know which is the intent i have to listen for this, and is it possible to do in this way.

thanks

Comment: what do u want to do with the camera intent. Generally such intents are captured by activities to do some action.

Answer (score 9):

For Receiving camera photo capture intent, try following code

```
public class CameraEventReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Toast.makeText(context, "New Photo Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

and in manifest, register the receiver:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

   <receiver
        android:name="com.android.application.CameraEventReciver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I implement this solution, but application receive only photos from camera, not videos. How should I change receiver params to make him receive videos?

Answer (score 2):

In your Android Manifest, you need to specify which intents you want to receive. For camera that'd be the following code (this goes within the `<application>` tags):

```
<receiver android:name="com.receiver.CameraReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In addition to that, you should add this to your `<intent-filter>` within the `<activity>` tags:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Finally, take care of the event in your activity's code like so:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    abortBroadcast();  
    //TODO: your code here
}
```

Comment: I tried using the above intent android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON with category DEFAULT and i am not receiving the intent to my onReceive method.

Comment: Edited my code a bit: added priority to the `<intent-filter>` tag, and an `abortBroadcast()` method in `onReceive()`. However, note that this might not work on devices that do not have a hard camera button. If this is the case, you might need another solution, but that already depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am trying on HTC HD which doesnt have hard cam button, how to do it for soft buttons can you please help me on this

Comment: Can you tell me what is it that you want to do? That other solution I have in mind works by tracking changes on the user's SD card. But that would mean that the user takes a picture with the default camera, and then your app is notified. So it'd help me if I knew more aobut your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread that will control your directory camera like:

```
FileObserver observer =new FileObserver("/mnt/extSd/DCIM/Camera/"){

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(event == FileObserver.CREATE ){
                            //Do Some things With The file
                        }
                    }};
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
}
observer.startWatching();
```