# hardware detect camera picture taken / shutter press

Tags: ios, iphone

I am orientating on developing an app to synchronize all pictures taken by the iPhone camera.

I searched quite a lot and can't find much about the hardware event for the camera shutter on the iPhone.

Is it possible like the [android CAMERA_BUTTON BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7482783/3883682) in the manifest, to listen if the camera button is pressed in general, without the app being specifically launched?

Or an overlay on the existing iOS camera app?

***Update 02-05-2018***

I din't managed to get a direct detection of the camera button, also no ongoing detection from pictures take from the camera([PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrarychangeobserver)). When the app is killed, all listeners are also killed. I am however using this when the app is booted up with the locationchange mechanism

In the end I used the [Using the Significant-Change Location Service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant_change_location_service) to get the detection of the changed pictures to synchronize, ongoing. I used the [NextCloud](https://github.com/nextcloud/ios) and [OwnCloud](https://github.com/owncloud/ios) as examples, which were containing this part.

Using the Significant-Change Location Service

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question right. There is no hardware camera button on an iPhone. You can specify a button to take the picture and, of course, you can listen if that button is pressed. However, only if you build your own camera app. You can't "listen" on the camera button of another camera app, since it is a sandboxed app.

Comment: I mean in general like the android broadcastreceiver listens app independent if an picture is taken. The point is to detect if an picture is taken at anytime, whitout the app running all the time.

Comment: The answer is no. You cannot detect shutter button pressed elsewhere. If you want to get images as soon as they are captured, then you can get those images by using `PHPhotoLibrary` by registering a change observer. For that your app should be running, at least in background state.

Comment: Would it be possible to keep it always running in the background state, not to miss any picture taken?
Or some sort of overlay on the existing camera app, to always be there when the default camera app is launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capturing of images and videos is an entire software related process managed by classes in the AVFoundation framework. The entire hardware of the iPhone is not accessible for applications and you cannot monitor the use of hardware directly. There are some system frameworks, but these won't help you. The AVFoundation doesn't have any notifications that it will post to registered observers.

All captured images and videos are put in the Photos library and the Photos library has notifications when something changes in the library. You can register your application as an observer for changes in the Photos library and you can specify the changes you want to observer. You can also collect the specific changes that have happened and have your application handle the changes in the Photos Library.

What I don't know is whether you can use this as a remote change and have your app being launched by iOS when it registers for that change in the Photos library. I do know that you can program your app to launch on reception of notifications, but I don't know if this can be done with [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrarychangeobserver) change observer. I would suggest to give it a try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver is indead working, bud its not easy to keep the app running. I'm now changing my plan to use push notifications to have an stable flow of code that will for sure be executed. It has good sides and bad sides, the sandbox app environment.