# Is it possible to listen to a system event when a new photo was added into the gallery?

Tags: flutter

I have my flutter app and I would like to perform a background task so when the user takes a picture with his camera, my app will get notified so it can do some checks upon this image/video.

Is there a way to listen to a gallery system event (or something else)

Comment: It's possible but only in Android. You can use Broadcast Receiver to get notified when the user capture a picture with camera. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482381/android-how-to-listen-to-camera-capture-in-broadcastreceiver      And for background task you can also perform the checks at android native side because it'll be little hard to perform background task at flutter/dart side when the application is terminated.